# Fake functionality on business websites

Tags: website-design, social-media

The company I work for currently has icons on it's website for things like Facebook, Twitter, Google+, etc. but they're just painted on images. Additionally, there isn't anything on the website that you logically would *want* to share, there's no blog posts or articles or events. It's a bare-bones website. There's also a search box that does nothing. These "dummy" items are all at the top right of the page and when I asked what the purpose of having them was my boss's response was that "companies put in fake links all the time, it makes it look like there's more there." Keeping in mind that the target demographic of visitors to the site are business managers looking for accounting software, does this seem like it would help, hurt, or not matter from a user experience standpoint?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> "companies put in fake links all the time, it makes it look like there's more there."

That's about the dumbest thing I've heard, no offense.

Visitors aren't dumb and shouldn't be treated as such. Only one thing will happen when a visitor finds out that you are lying to them: *they will simply leave and never come back*.

I suggest you do 1 of 2 things: 1) create the social media accounts that you are linking to and make the search box work or 2) remove the "fake functionality" as fast as you can.

Answer (score 3):

1. I would definitely remove the search box.
2. However, if...

   - you don't actually have/yet have the social media accounts, or
   - there are issues with your accounts, e.g. you don't have time/energy/resources to devote to

     - creating them
     - making them presentable
     - don't yet have/are still thinking about content
     - etc

   ...then you should at least NOT MAKE the SoMe icons (FB, Twitter, G+) live links/hrefs.

   - That is, remove any anchors (`<a href="...">text or image</a>`) or JavaScript `onClick()` events/handlers.
   - In other words, the mouse should not change from an arrow to a hand pointing finger when hovering over the icon.

   The benefit of this is that it will at least ***NOT ALLUDE*** to some actionable content in/under the link, which would:

   - at best, confuse the user, or
   - at worst, lead the user to think that your site is broken and you are too lazy and/or inept to notice and fix it.

   At the same time, this hopefully will have the upside of implying that you have a SoMe presence or at least are thinking about it (which I hope you/your employer does/is).

   It may be a slight annoyance when they can't instantly get to one/any SoMe profile page, however.  So, you should provide **SOME WAY** of contacting you... at least have a form, a link to a form, or an email icon that works (with a `<a href="mailto:sales@mycompany.com">` link)

Comment: The only thing that I find problematic with this approach is that implying the company has a social media presence when it doesn't strikes me as underhanded. The company intends to begin managing a facebook page and blog, so at that point I would be happy to include the links. But until such a point the idea of having the icons without any sort of notice that there's no actual content yet makes me incredibly uncomfortable.

Comment: as I said... I gave you options, and I don't know what your situation is... whether or not you have ANY SoMe pages or not, why you don't, or why you have no content, etc...  All, you said is the links are dummies, and that (what seems like in your opinion) there's nothing TO share.  Well, honestly, you/he are lacking some marketing creativiting.  There must be lots that you can share via social media... e.g. when you have deals, reminders of tax deadlines, links to tax forms, instructions, a "glossary word a day" tweet, etc...  I could come up with a hundred things.

Comment: I think your view of this and your acceptance of the answer is based on a purely technical one, without factoring in what SoMe and content really means and is, and how you properly deal with it.  I think you need to have a better conversation with your boss, or edit your question.  B/c, based on how you've asked it... I'ved given you completely legitimate, solutions.  And, frankly, something that can help you create a plan towards an online and/or offline marketing campaign

Comment: I'm aware that there's plenty that *could* be done, I'm just more concerned about the *present*. There is no share-able content and nowhere to share it at the present, and it's not in my control to change that. I am not in charge of actually creating any social content, merely skinning the website to what we *do* have. My question and view are not therefore about approaching the issue with the idea of relying on future creation of social sites, they are about the legitimacy of implying features that aren't present.

Comment: This is not an issue of user experience then.  These are not features of your site.  They are nothing more than banners, badges.  Nothing different than putting logos of companies, or magazines/newspaper some PR/writeups have shown up in.  Whether or not it's dishonest is NOT the issue.  If the links DON'T do anything.  Then they are not fake functionality.  They are not features at all.  Your question is one of morality.

Comment: I was looking for information about what the user experience knowledge is of the specific case where a user is presented with something indicative of a feature that doesn't actually exist. Does it frustrate a user that they can't access the functionality/content? Is it ignored? Does it actually improve their experience in the interface to have options presented in a very minimal site, even if the options don't offer anything? If a user comes to the site looking for information about our company and our software, I wanted to know how the icons would affect their experience in that use case.

Comment: I have found, that depending on the size and type of business, and sophistication of it's buyers.  Having dead SoMe links tends to imply that the company is *"Social Media aware"* and at least thinking about some presence, and they infer that "it's on its way".  You might help bridge the gap, by adding some text under your icons to the effect of **"Look out for our new Social Media pages... coming soon"**  or  **"Check back soon for our new Social Media pages"**

Comment: sure.  HTH.  Maybe you've already tried this... but, encourage your boss to simply create those accounts?  If you have, just curious what, if anything were his reasons for resistance?

Comment: The resistance seemed to come from just not wanting to do it differently or change it. The site was commissioned from a third party and nobody's touched it other than me and I've only started working on it recently (it was a horrible, horrible, horrible site from a code/markup perspective, but that's a story for another day). So I think it was just an attitude of "easier to do nothing and say it's fine than to say it's not fine and do something."

Answer (score 1):

> These "dummy" items are all at the top right of the page and when I
>   asked what the purpose of having them was my boss's response was that
>   "companies put in fake links all the time, it makes it look like
>   there's more there."

This is simply untrue. One of the main tenants underpinning UX is the removal of distraction from the page, in order to focus on the call to action.

> Keeping in mind that the target demographic of visitors to the site
>   are business managers looking for accounting software, does this seem
>   like it would help, hurt, or not matter from a user experience
>   standpoint?

Your answer is right there in the question: "user experience". Simply ask yourself what the user experiences if they click a fake link or attempt to use a non-functioning search box? I believe anyone in your office, even your derp-dee-doo boss, could nail down the right answer on their first try.

Confusion; possible frustration. That's what gets experienced and, thus, emotionally associated with your brand.